# Salvar conteúdo textarea como arquivo de texto

Tags: php, txt

Preciso fazer um código que ao inserir o que é requisitado na `textarea` e apertar o botão `submit`, salve o conteúdo inserido na `textarea` em um `.txt` (com quebra de linha. Por ex: Se alguém já deu submit antes e salvou, não apagar o que já está salvo, apenas quebrar uma linha e adicionar o recente).

E um outro botão <kbd>Participando?</kbd> puxar do `.txt` salvo o conteúdo para uma `div` ou uma `textarea` (que só ficará visível após apertar este botão).

**Meu código (index.php):**

```
<form action="salvar.php" method="post">
   <center>
   <center>
   <br><h2 style="font: Ventana; text-shadow: 0 0 0.1em gray; color:gray;"><font face="Candara"><font color="redyellow">{Sorteador Skins}</font></h2>
   <br><h2 style="font: Ventana; text-shadow: 0 0 0.1em gray; color:gray;"><font face="Candara"><font color="purpleyellow">[Boa Sorte]</font></h2>
   <br><h2 style="font: Ventana; text-shadow: 0 0 0.1em gray; color:gray;"><font face="Candara"><font color="purple">(By: PumP)</font></h2>
   </center>               
   <textarea required name="ccs" id="ccs" placeholder="Insira seu nick :)" type="text" class="form-control" style="max-width: 800px; min-width: 800px; min-height: 200px; max-height: 200px; text-align: center; resize: none; color: red; background-color: #2b323d"></textarea>
   <br>
   <br>
   <center>
   <input type="submit" id="enviar" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cadastrar">
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" id="participantes" class="btn btn-sucess" value="Participando?">
</form>
```

**salvar.php:**

```
<?php
$txt = $_POST['ccs'];
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $ess);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente vamos aos erros.

O primeiro está no modo como você está abrindo o arquivo. Segundo a documentação do `PHP`, o modo **w** é utilizado apenas para criação de arquivos.

No seu caso o modo correto é **a+**. Esse modo permitirá que o você abra o arquivo para escrita e leitura.

O segundo está no nome da variável `$ess`, ela não existe. O correto seria `$txt`

O terceiro erro está no botão "**Participando?**", como ele está dentro do `form` e está setado como `submit`, logo, ele tem a função de enviar o conteúdo do `textarea` para a url `/salvar.php`

Agora, vamos as soluções.

Uma das formas de acrescentar novas informações ao arquivo, é como te expliquei anteriormente, utilizar o modo **a+** com a função `fopen`.

Uma outra forma, é utilizar a função `file_put_contents`. Essa função permitirá criar um arquivo ou acrescentar novas informações a ele.

Na correção do problema do botão "**Participando?**", você também tem duas opções:

1. Criar um `button` com o `type:button` e com o evento `click`, você chamar uma requisição com o `XMLHttpRequest`
2. Criar uma `anchor` que possa te levar para a url `/ler_arquivo.php`, por exemplo.

---

**Como fazer**

Espero que você possa ler os comentários dos arquivos com todo cuidado. A minha intenção é que esse código possa auxiliá-la no entendimento da solução.
Espero, também, que você leia os links que deixei no final para conhecer mais a fundo e escolher a melhor opção para seu código.

**index.html**

```
<form action="salvar.php" method="post">
   <center>
   <center>
   <br><h2 style="font: Ventana; text-shadow: 0 0 0.1em gray; color:gray;"><font face="Candara"><font color="redyellow">{Sorteador Skins}</font></h2>
   <br><h2 style="font: Ventana; text-shadow: 0 0 0.1em gray; color:gray;"><font face="Candara"><font color="purpleyellow">[Boa Sorte]</font></h2>
   <br><h2 style="font: Ventana; text-shadow: 0 0 0.1em gray; color:gray;"><font face="Candara"><font color="purple">(By: PumP)</font></h2>
   </center>               
   <textarea required name="ccs" id="ccs" placeholder="Insira seu nick :)" type="text" class="form-control" style="max-width: 800px; min-width: 800px; min-height: 200px; max-height: 200px; text-align: center; resize: none; color: red; background-color: #2b323d"></textarea>
   <br>
   <br>
   <center>
   <input type="submit" id="enviar" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cadastrar">
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="button" id="participantes" class="btn btn-sucess" value="Participando?">
</form>


<script>
    var participantes = document.querySelector("#participantes");
    var textarea = document.querySelector("#ccs");

    participantes.addEventListener("click", function() {

        /* Cria o objeto responsável pela requisição */
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        /* 
         * Adiciona um evento para capturar os dados quando a
         * requisição for finalizada e joga-las no textarea
         */
        req.addEventListener("loadend", function(result) {
            textarea.value = result.target.response;
        });

        /* Abre a conexão com o servidor */
        req.open("GET", "capturar_arquivo.php");

        /* Envia o pedido */
        req.send();

    });
</script>
```

**salvar.php**

```
<?php

$filename = "arquivo.txt";

/*
 * Verifica se o conteúdo da textarea `ccs` foi enviado
 * Essa condição irá evitar erros
 */
if (isset($_POST["ccs"])) {

    /* Captura o conteúdo enviado */
    $ccs = $_POST["ccs"];

    /*
     * Abre o arquivo com o modo a+
     * Esse modo permite abrir o arquivo
     * tanto para o modo de leitura, quanto
     * para o modo de escrita, além de colocar
     * o ponteiro no final do arquivo.
     */
    $file = fopen($filename, "a+");

    /*
     * Escreve o conteúdo enviado e adiciona
     * uma quebra de linha no arquivo.
     */
    fwrite($file, $ccs);
    fwrite($file, PHP_EOL);

    /**
     * Fecha o arquivo
     */
    fclose($file);

    /**
     * Caso você opte pela função `file_put_contents`,
     * estou deixando o link da documentação para você
     * dar uma estudada.
     */

    /**
     * Volta para a página index.html
     */
    header("Location: index.html");
}
```

**capturar_arquivo.php**

> Há 3 formas simples para capturar o conteúdo de um arquivo.
>   Irei postar as três, porém, deixarei duas delas irei apenas citar. Deixarei o link para que você possa ler mais sobre elas.
>   Espero que você possa ler as documentações que irei deixar
>   para poder escolher melhor.

```
<?php

$filename = "arquivo.txt";

/* ************************************* */
/* Forma 1                               */
/* ************************************* */

/**
 * Arquivo o arquivo no modo somente leitura
 */
$file = fopen($filename, "r");

/* Variável onde ficará o conteúdo do arquivo */
$content = "";

/**
 * "Divide" o arquivo em várias partes de 1024 bytes
 * e depois percorre todas elas, juntando-as.
 */
while (($line = fread($file, 1024)) != false) {
    $content .= $line;
}


/* ************************************* */
/* Forma 2 - Irei deixar comentada       */
/* ************************************* */
// Aqui você pode utilizar a função "file_get_contents"


/* ************************************* */
/* Forma 3 - Irei deixar comentada       */
/* ************************************* */
// Aqui você poderá utilizar a função "file" e "implode"


/* Imprime o conteúdo na tela */
echo $content;
```

**Links:**

- [Documentação do fopen](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
- [Documentação do fwrite](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)
- [Documentação do fread](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)
- [Documentação do file_get_contents](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
- [Documentação do file_put_contents](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)
- [Documentação do file](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)
- [Documentação do implode](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 0):

O código do salvar.php apresenta este erro: "Esta página não está funcionando
dominio.com não consegue atender a esta solicitação no momento.
HTTP ERROR 500"

```
<?php
$filename = "arquivo.txt";


if (isset($_POST["ccs"])) {


    $ccs = $_POST["ccs"];


    $file = fopen($filename, "a+");


    fwrite($file, $ccs);
    fwrite($file, PHP_EOL);


    fclose($file);


    header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: Se possível poste como comentário da próxima vez. Vai melhorar e eu saberei se há alguma outra dúvida. O erro nesse código é que está faltando uma chave `}` antes do `?>`. Ao remover os comentários você,  provavelmente, removeu esse caractere.